# Как сделать сворачивание и разворачивание элементов списка

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="catmain">
        <li class="catmain-list">
            <a href="#">brown</a>
            <ul class="catmain-list-sublist">
                <li>brown 1</li>
                <li>brown 2</li>
                <li>brown 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="catmain-list">
            <a href="#">green</a>
            <ul class="catmain-list-sublist">
                <li>green 1</li>
                <li>green 2</li>
                <li>green 3</li>
                <li>green 4</li>
                <li>green 5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="catmain-list">
            <a href="#">red</a>
            <ul class="catmain-list-sublist">
                <li>red 11</li>
                <li>red 22</li>
                <li>red 33</li>
                <li>red 44</li>
                <li>red 55</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        alert(1);
        $(".catmain-list").toggle(
            $(this).find('ul').css("display", "block");
            alert(1);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('ul').css("display", "none");
        );
    }

</script>

<style>
    ul { margin:10px; list-style:inside circle; font-weight:bold; }
    li { cursor:pointer; }
    .catmain-list-sublist{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Как сделать если например brown то разворачивается весь список под ним, а если было что то открыто то это сворачивается. То есть открыто что то одно ?

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаешь для открытого класс active. Все закрываешь, а затем active открываешь.

**Добавлено:**

Примерно так:

```
$('.catmain-list > a').click(function(){
  $('.catmain-list-sublist').hide();
  $(this).addClass('active').show();
})
```

или даже лучше так:
CSS:

```
 .catmain-list > ul{display:none;}
 .catmain-list.active > ul{display:block}
```

JS:

```
$('.catmain-list > a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: да, я об этом догадывался, прошу подсказать реализацию ... я в jquery очень слаб

Answer (score 0):

На хабрахабре была про это [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38208/). Смотрите пример "Гармошка". В целом все сводится к методам `addClass("active")` и `removeClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

[Статья](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)